# Random moving image won't move

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the script, but it doesn't seem to work. I have no error messages yet the image just sits there doing nothing. I have absolutely no idea where the problem lies, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
    <script src='script.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class='a'></div>


</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
 div.a {
    width: 50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:red;
    position:fixed;
}
```

JavaScript

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    animateDiv();

});

function makeNewPosition() {


    var h = $(window).height() - 50;
    var w = $(window).width() - 50;

    var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
    var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

    return [nh, nw];

}

function animateDiv() {
    var newq = makeNewPosition();
    var oldq = $('.a').offset();
    var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);

    $('.a').animate({
        top: newq[0],
        left: newq[1]
    }, speed, function () {
        animateDiv();
    });

};

function calcSpeed(prev, next) {

    var x = Math.abs(prev[1] - next[1]);
    var y = Math.abs(prev[0] - next[0]);

    var greatest = x > y ? x : y;

    var speedModifier = 0.1;

    var speed = Math.ceil(greatest / speedModifier);

    return speed;

}
```

Comment: works fine, check [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eky7tt4o/), your script requires jquery, so you have to include it before your script

Comment: then why doesnt it work in codepen?

Comment: just include query library before your script

Comment: where and how do i add the jquery?

Comment: please refer to answer below to learn how to include jquery in your source files, and here link to working [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwVpNN).

Answer (score 0):

you should link in the jquery library from here: https://jquery.com/ just download the library and reference it in the html

This is how you add the file to the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<head>
   <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
   <script src='script.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class='a'></div>


</body>
</html>
```